# Illegal char <:> at index 51: com.example.AppName.app-mergeDebugResources-29:/values/values.xml

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

Hello I am trying to compile and run my Android Project and this error has occurred

Illegal char <:> at index 51: com.example.capstonecafe.app-mergeDebugResources-29:/values/values.xml

I have checked my values.xml which is below

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
xmlns:ns2="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
<attr format="enum" name="animateCircleAngleTo">
    <enum name="bestChoice" value="0"/>
    <enum name="closest" value="1"/>
    <enum name="clockwise" value="2"/>
    <enum name="antiClockwise" value="3"/>
    <enum name="constraint" value="4"/>
</attr>
```

I have 2 errors on this file which are

```
xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
xmlns:ns2="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2"
```

If I remove one or the other many other errors occur on the file.
I have tried putting this line of code in my gradle properties

```
 android.enableJetifier=true
```

But my application closes right after the build is successful

Full Error Output

```
 1: Task failed with an exception.
 -----------
 * What went wrong:
 Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
 > A failure occurred while executing 
 com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.ResourceCompilerRunnable
  > Resource compilation failed (Failed to compile values resource file  
  Cause: java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 
  51: com.example.capstonecafe.app-mergeDebugResources- 
  29:/values/values.xml). Check logs for more details.
```

Activity.xml for the dependencies

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:background="@drawable/bg1">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:src="@drawable/cafeh"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/txtquote"
        android:text="@string/quote"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#6E2C00"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:fontFamily="@font/carterone_regular"
        android:textSize="15dp"/>





</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
        android:id="@+id/btnsignup"
        app:buttonColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Sign Up"
        android:textColor="#6E2C00"
        app:cornerRadius="4dp"
        app:shadowColor="#6E2C00"
        app:shadowEnabled="true"
        app:shadowHeight="5dp" />

    <info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
        android:id="@+id/btnsignin"
        app:buttonColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Sign In"
        android:textColor="#6E2C00"
        app:cornerRadius="4dp"
        app:shadowColor="#6E2C00"
        app:shadowEnabled="true"
        app:shadowHeight="5dp" />

</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Is it `xmlns:ns2="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2"` your custom xmls? that you are using?

Comment: Im not sure. It just popped up when I was compiling. If I remove it many other errors occur in the file containing "ns2"

Comment: @lvor I'm not talking to remove it. I just asked that are you using this custom `xmls` or not. try to change from `xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` to `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"`. Let me know if not work.

Comment: Yes its still not working. When I hover the mouse it says URI is not registered

Comment: These errors happened after I added these into my dependencies. implementation 'info.hoang8f:fbutton:1.0.5'
    implementation 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'

Comment: @lvor can you share `XML` code where you are using the code of these dependencies.

Comment: @M DEV I have updated the post. I am only using one of the dependencies at the moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have opened the values.xml file in the debug\values. These files are not supposed to be edited. As for your error, you can try either of the below

1. First try Invalidate and restart cache then see if it works
2. If still it does not work check all your xml files in the res directory to see where you have wrongfully entered an <:> character